# Why dictionary generator doesn't work correctly

Tags: python, dictionary, generator

I need to read CSV file and fill dict by data from file. So I wrote one method

```
def read_data(self):
    with open('storage/data/heart.csv') as f:
            self.raw_data = {
                len(self.raw_data): {
                    'age':line[0],
                    'sex':line[1],
                    'cp':line[2],
                    'trtbps':line[3],
                    'chol':line[4],
                    'fbs':line[5],
                    'restecg':line[6],
                    'thalachh':line[7]
                    } for line in csv.reader(f)}
```

But print(raw_data) returns this:

```
{0: {'age': '57', 'sex': '0', 'cp': '1', 'trtbps': '130', 'chol': '236', 'fbs': '0', 'restecg': '0', 'thalachh': '174'}}
```

As u can see my method saves only 1 line to dict and this line is the last line from the file. Pls help me

Comment: Did you mean `len(line)` instead of `len(self.raw_data)`? Otherwise you're using the same key over and over in your loop. Otherwise if that is just supposed to be an index, there's no reason for a `dict` just store in a `list` and you can use `enumerate` later to get the `(index,value)` of each element

Comment: Only one dict key (`len(self.raw_data)`) is being written to. Why would one expect to see more keys?

Comment: @CoryKramer: `len(line)` doesn't make sense either. There could be 2 lines with the same length

Answer (score 0):

`len(self.raw_data)` is evaluated ones at the start and does not change inside the dict comprehension. Just use a normal loop or `enumerate` like:

```
def read_data(self):
    with open('storage/data/heart.csv') as f:
            self.raw_data = {
                i: {
                    'age':line[0],
                    'sex':line[1],
                    'cp':line[2],
                    'trtbps':line[3],
                    'chol':line[4],
                    'fbs':line[5],
                    'restecg':line[6],
                    'thalachh':line[7]
                    } for line in i, enumerate(csv.reader(f))}
```

Comment: As I mentioned in the comments, if the key is just the index, no need for a `dict` at all, just store in a `list`. They can later `enumerate` to get the index and value of each element